# Insert a row n times

Tags: excel, vba

I´ve an Excel file with 10 Columns. In columns 2, 3, 4 I have a number or a dash.
If the sum of these 3 cells is greater than 1, I need to replace that entire row with n rows that have only one of the columns with the value 1 but the other cells stay the same.

```
Example
1 - -  #-> leave it as is
- 2 -  #-> replace that row with 2 rows : - 1 - ; - 1 -
2 - 1  #-> replace that row with 3 rows : 1 - - ; 1 - - ; - - 1;
```

I managed to iterate from bottom up, but I´m having trouble storing a row in memory, manipulate it and insert below.

```vb
Sub Test()      
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim count20, count40, count45, total, i As Integer
    
    Set rng = Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))
        
    For i = rng.Cells.count To 1 Step -1
        count20 = 0
        count40 = 0
        count45 = 0
        total = 0
            
        count20 = Cells(rng.Item(i).Row, 10).Value
        If count20 > 1 Then
            total = total + count20
        End If
            
        count40 = Cells(rng.Item(i).Row, 11).Value
        If count40 > 1 Then
            total = total + count40
        End If
            
        count45 = Cells(rng.Item(i).Row, 12).Value
        If count45 > 1 Then
            total = total + count45
        End If
            
        If total <> 0 Then
            MsgBox total
        End If
     
    Next i     
End Sub
```

Comment: In the third example you say that you need three rows, yet your code will find only two. Could you clarify? I mean, In this example Count20 is 2 and will be added to total, but count45 is 1 and will not be added.

Comment: don´t trust my code... I should count 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

I’ve provided alternative code based on your latest comment.  It uses columns J-L (10-12) as the numeric cells to be changed, and columns A-I (1-9) and M-AD (13-30) as the cells with text to be preserved.  As before, sheet 1 starting in row 3 is assumed, and you can change this to whatever you need.

```
Option Explicit
Sub testJtoL()
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, c As Long, _
insertR As Long, TopRow As Long, BottomRow As Long
Dim b As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

'*** This code is based your values being in Columns J-L (10-12) in sheet 1 ***

'Set sheet 1 as ws
Set ws = Sheet1

'Sheet1 column J is used here to get your last row
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

'*** This code is based your values starting in Row 3 ***
For c = LastRow To 3 Step -1
    'Determine number of rows to insert based on sum of that row
    insertR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(c, 10), Cells(c, 12))) - 1
    If insertR = 0 Then GoTo skip
    
    'STEP 1 insert the correct number of rows
    With ws.Range(Cells(c + 1, 1), Cells(c + insertR, 30))
        .Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End With
    
    'STEP 2 fill the values into the correct number of rows
    insertR = insertR + 1
    With ws.Range(Cells(c, 1), Cells(c, 30))
        .Resize(insertR, 30).Value = .Value
    End With
    
    TopRow = c
    If insertR = 0 And c = 3 Then
        BottomRow = c
            Else
            BottomRow = c + insertR - 1
    End If
    
    'STEP 3 replace all numbers with 1 or "-"
    'Replace numbers in column J
    If ws.Range(Cells(c, 10), Cells(c, 10)).Value = "-" Then GoTo SkipA
    i = ws.Range(Cells(c, 10), Cells(c, 10)).Value
    j = 1
    
    For Each b In ws.Range(Cells(TopRow, 10), Cells(BottomRow, 10))
    
    If j <= i Then
        b.Value = 1
        b.Offset(0, 1).Value = "-"
        b.Offset(0, 2).Value = "-"
            Else
            b.Value = "-"
    End If
    j = j + 1
    
    Next b
    
SkipA:
    'Replace numbers in column K
    j = 1
    For Each b In ws.Range(Cells(TopRow, 11), Cells(BottomRow, 11))
    If b.Value = "-" Then GoTo SkipB
    i = b.Value
    
    If j <= i Then
        b.Value = 1
        b.Offset(0, 1).Value = "-"
            Else
            b.Value = "-"
    End If
    j = j + 1
        
SkipB:
    Next b
    
    'Replace numbers in column L
    j = 1
    For Each b In ws.Range(Cells(TopRow, 12), Cells(BottomRow, 12))
    If b.Value = "-" Then GoTo SkipC
    i = b.Value
    
    If j <= i Then
        b.Value = 1
            Else
            b.Value = "-"
    End If
    j = j + 1
    
SkipC:
    Next b
    
skip:
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for taking time to solve this. Where I work I get excel report with orders with 20 columns and many rows. Each row as 3 cells in particular that represent the number of TypeA, TypeB and TypeC objects. At least one cell is 1, but I can have all 3 cells having numbers up to 999. To import to another software, I need to have only 1 Type with only 1 unit per row. Ex: If the first row was 1 ; 1 ; 999 , the output would be 1001 rows the same text for the 1001 rows. = 1x[ 1 ; - ;-] + 1x [- ; 1 ; -] + 999x [- ; - ; 1], keeping the other cells on the left and right per row. Repeat ...

Comment: Code amended - please let me know how it goes.

Comment: kevin999, When I ran your code I cried. Perfect, and the comments were a great help also understand !!! I I´ll ran this code in columns 10, 11 and 12, could you show me how to duplicate/keep the same values that were on the original row on columns [1 to 9] and [13 - 30] for each repetition. If I repeat the 1st row 10 times, keep the same text on the left and right for the new rows. Once again thank you so much.